# How do you change the displayed order of ActiveScaffold "actions"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activescaffold

I am using ActiveScaffold in a Ruby on Rails app, and have replaced the default "actions" text in the table (ie. "edit", "delete", "show") with icons using CSS. I have also added a couple of custom actions with action_link.add ("move" and "copy").

For clarity, **I would like to have the icons displayed in a different order** than they are.  Specifically, I would like "edit" to be the first icon displayed.

I seem to be able to change the order of the action_links by the changing the order of definition in the controller.  I have also been able to change the order of the default actions by first config.actions.excluding everything, and then adding them with config.actions.add in a specific order.

However, **my custom actions always seem to appear *before* the default actions** in the list.

Ideally I would like them to display "edit" "copy" "move" "delete" (ie - built-in, custom, custom, built-in).  Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

One idea I had was to re-define "edit" as a custom action (with the default functionality), but I don't know how to go about this either.

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat:** I don't know *ActiveScaffold*. This answer is based on me reading its source code.

It looks like the `action_links` variable is a custom data structure, called `ActionLinks`. It's defined in `ActiveScaffold::DataStructures`.

Internally, it has a `@set` variable, which is not a `Set` at all, but an `Array`. `ActionLinks` has an `add`, `delete`, and `each` methods that serve as gatekeepers of this `@set` variable.

When displaying the links, *ActiveScaffold* does this (in `_list_actions.rhtml`):

```
<% active_scaffold_config.action_links.each :record do |link| -%>
  # Displays the link (code removed for brevity)
<% end -%>
```

So, short of extending `ActiveScaffold::DataStructures::ActionLinks` to add a method to sort the values in `@set` differently, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it, at least not generally.

If I were you, I'd add something called `order_by!`, where you pass it an array of symbols, with the proper order, and it resorts `@set`. That way, you can call it after you're done adding your custom actions.